# jquery fetchJSON selecting the correct object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

So at the moment I am trying to create a click event that can be re-used throughout my application,

The basic flow of the nav, is that a user would click on a link, click that link will get a getJSON request, the JSON is parsed and returned in a subnav, however the point where I am coming unstuck a bit is accessing the correct object in the JSON to loop through the create the sub-nav, below is my code.

```
$(".primary a").on("click", function(e){

    var type = "data."+$(this).data('type');

    if($(".secondary").hasClass("bounceInUp")) {
        $(".secondary").removeClass("bounceInUp").addClass("bounceOutDown");
    }

    $.getJSON("js/data.json", function(data){

        var items = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            items.push('<li><a href="" data-name="'+ val +'"><img src="img/wood-nav.jpg" /></a></li>');
        });

        console.log(items);
        $(".secondary ul").empty();
        $(".secondary ul").html(items);
        $(".secondary").removeClass("bounceOutDown").addClass("animated bounceInUp");

    });
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

My JSON looks like the following,

```
{
    "doors" : {
        "1" : "door 1",
        "2" : "door 2",
        "3" : "door 3",
        "4" : "door 4",
        "5" : "door 5",
        "6" : "door 6",
        "7" : "door 7",
        "8" : "door 8",
        "9" : "door 9",
        "10": "door 10"
    },

    "handles" : {
        "1" : "handle 1",
        "2" : "handle 2",
        "3" : "handle 3",
        "4" : "handle 4",
        "5" : "handle 5",
        "6" : "handle 6",
        "7" : "handle 7",
        "8" : "handle 8",
        "9" : "handle 9",
        "10": "handle 10"
    },

    "worktops" : {
        "1" : "worktop 1",
        "2" : "worktop 2",
        "3" : "worktop 3",
        "4" : "worktop 4",
        "5" : "worktop 5",
        "6" : "worktop 6",
        "7" : "worktop 7",
        "8" : "worktop 8",
        "9" : "worktop 9",
        "10": "worktop 10" 
    },

    "floors" : {
        "1" : "floor 1",
        "2" : "floor 2",
        "3" : "floor 3",
        "4" : "floor 4",
        "5" : "floor 5",
        "6" : "floor 6",
        "7" : "floor 7",
        "8" : "floor 8",
        "9" : "floor 9",
        "10": "floor 10" 
    },

    "walls" : {
        "1" : "wall 1",
        "2" : "wall 2",
        "3" : "wall 3",
        "4" : "wall 4",
        "5" : "wall 5",
        "6" : "wall 6",
        "7" : "wall 7",
        "8" : "wall 8",
        "9" : "wall 9",
        "10": "wall 10" 
    }

}
```

What have a i tried already? I have tried constructing the data object name outside of the loop and then passing it in, so if I were click on doors for example `var type` would then be = to "doors", I then concatinate that on to `data.` however when looping through that I get his error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '9' in data.doors

It seems that I cannot go into my the object I need based on a click but there must be a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to iterate over the `type` variable, wich is a `string`.

```
var type = "data."+$(this).data('type');
```

Try this instead:

```
var type = $(this).data('type');

$.getJSON("js/data.json", function(data){

        var items = [],
            data = data[type];

        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            items.push('<li><a href="" data-name="'+ val +'"><img src="img/wood-nav.jpg" /></a></li>');
        });
        //...
```

Answer (score 0):

I done this as a quick test:

```
var temp = {
"doors": {
    "1": "door 1",
    "2": "door 2",
    "3": "door 3",
    "4": "door 4",
    "5": "door 5",
    "6": "door 6",
    "7": "door 7",
    "8": "door 8",
    "9": "door 9",
    "10": "door 10"
},
"handles": {
    "1": "handle 1",
    "2": "handle 2",
    "3": "handle 3",
    "4": "handle 4",
    "5": "handle 5",
    "6": "handle 6",
    "7": "handle 7",
    "8": "handle 8",
    "9": "handle 9",
    "10": "handle 10"
},
"worktops": {
    "1": "worktop 1",
    "2": "worktop 2",
    "3": "worktop 3",
    "4": "worktop 4",
    "5": "worktop 5",
    "6": "worktop 6",
    "7": "worktop 7",
    "8": "worktop 8",
    "9": "worktop 9",
    "10": "worktop 10"
},
"floors": {
    "1": "floor 1",
    "2": "floor 2",
    "3": "floor 3",
    "4": "floor 4",
    "5": "floor 5",
    "6": "floor 6",
    "7": "floor 7",
    "8": "floor 8",
    "9": "floor 9",
    "10": "floor 10"
},
"walls": {
    "1": "wall 1",
    "2": "wall 2",
    "3": "wall 3",
    "4": "wall 4",
    "5": "wall 5",
    "6": "wall 6",
    "7": "wall 7",
    "8": "wall 8",
    "9": "wall 9",
    "10": "wall 10"
}
};

alert(temp.doors['9']);
```

Which works fine.

If i do `alert(temp.doors.9);` i get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

So maybe trying doing this:

```
temp["subObjectName"]["subSubObjectName"];
```

And it should work as your JSON is valid!